# How can I use Ant-design-vue using cdn?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, antd, netsuite, ant-design-vue

I am trying to build a Vue macro app to use in NetSuite for specific functionality. Since I cannot use npm or other package installers, I need to use CDN. The Vue app is working, and even Ant Design is also working. The only problem I am having is that it is not picking up the styles for any Ant Design component. This is my code:

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Auto Refresh Page</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3.2.31"></script>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/ant-design-vue@3.2.20/dist/antd.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </link>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/dayjs.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/plugin/customParseFormat.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/plugin/weekday.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/plugin/localeData.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/plugin/weekOfYear.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/plugin/weekYear.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/plugin/advancedFormat.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/plugin/quarterOfYear.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
  </div>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/ant-design-vue@3.2.20/dist/antd.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    const app = Vue.createApp({
      el: "#app",
      data() {
        return {
          moduleLoaded: false,
          currentRecordModule: null,
          backgroundProcess: false,
          showModal: false,
        };
      },
      methods: {
        init() {
          const currentRecordModule = require(['N/currentRecord'], (currentRecord) => {
            this.moduleLoaded = true
            this.currentRecordModule = currentRecord
          });
        },

        reloadPage() {
          location.reload(true)
        },

        showAlert() {
          this.showModal = true
          const iframeHtml = '<iframe src="${activeBgTaskUrl}" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; border: none;"></iframe>';
          
        },

        handleShowBackgroundProcessAlert(event) {
          if (event.target.id === 'showBackgroundProcessAlert') {
            this.showAlert()
          }
        },
      },

      mounted() {
        console.log('App mounted')
        this.init();
        document.addEventListener('click', this.handleShowBackgroundProcessAlert)
      },

      },

      template: `<a-button icon="search" type="primary">Primary Button</a-button>
    <a-modal v-model:visible="showModal" title="Basic Modal" @ok="handleOk">
      <p>Some contents...</p>
      <p>Some contents...</p>
      <p>Some contents...</p>
    </a-modal>`
    });
    app.mount('#app');
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to open a modal in the `showAlert` function. I have tried multiple things, including directly accessing the Ant Design global variable, using the import statement, and using the require method, but none of them are working. The button is showing, but without any styles, and the same goes for the modal. For those who know NetSuite, creating a Suitelet is not an option.

**EDIT**

It is not loading the ant design components too and giving me these warnings:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: a-modal
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.
```

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: a-button
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.
```

**Edit-2**

My source in browser is looking like this:

[image]

I am able to access the Vue but not antd. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

In the Ant Design Vue (antdv) documentation, there is a section explaining how to import it in the browser:

#### [Import in Browser](https://www.antdv.com/docs/vue/introduce#import-in-browser)

Add `script` and `link` tags in your browser and use the global variable `antd`.

---

You need to add the global variable antd in app.use().

For example:

```js
app.use(antd).mount('#app');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just want to extend **@saravanan-nandhan**'s answer. Need to add additional **components** option in **createApp** with element specification.

```
const { createApp } = Vue;

createApp({
  components: {
    AButton: window['antd'].Button,
    AModal: window['antd'].Modal,
  },
  ...
}).mount('#app');
```

Comment: I have already tried that option but it is giving me undefined on window['antd'] and not allowing me to access properties inside it

Comment: @IshaqKamran Did you add all the head links? Please check `Network` section in Dev Tools, if all links are loaded as expected (Status code = 200). Please also check "window" variable in Dev Tool's "Console", does it include `antd` key

Comment: Yes, all links are loaded as expected. But the window variable in console doesnot include antd key

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to resolve it. The issue was with the version compatibility of Vue and Ant Design, as well as the difference in the script providers. Previously, I used CDNJS for Vue and UNPKG for Ant Design. Now, I used CDNJS for both of them. This is what my final script looks like:

```
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3.2.31"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/dayjs.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/plugin/customParseFormat.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/plugin/weekday.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/plugin/localeData.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/plugin/weekOfYear.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/plugin/weekYear.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/plugin/advancedFormat.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/plugin/quarterOfYear.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ant-design-vue/2.2.8/antd.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ant-design-vue/2.2.8/antd.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score -1):

Ensure Correct CSS Link that the version of the Ant Design Vue CSS file matches the version of the Ant Design Vue script. In your code, both are set to 3.2.20, which is good.

Vue Version Compatibility Make sure that the version of Vue (3.2.31 in your case) is compatible with the version of Ant Design Vue you are using (3.2.20). As of my last update, this should be compatible.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Auto Refresh Page</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.31"></script>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/ant-design-vue@3.2.20/dist/antd.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/dayjs.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/plugin/customParseFormat.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/plugin/weekday.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/plugin/localeData.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/plugin/weekOfYear.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/plugin/weekYear.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/plugin/advancedFormat.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/plugin/quarterOfYear.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/ant-design-vue@3.2.20/dist/antd.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <a-button type="primary" @click="showAlert">Show Modal</a-button>
    <a-modal v-model:visible="showModal" title="Basic Modal" @ok="handleOk">
      <p>Some contents...</p>
      <p>Some contents...</p>
      <p>Some contents...</p>
    </a-modal>
  </div>
  <script>
    const { createApp } = Vue;

    createApp({
      data() {
        return {
          moduleLoaded: false,
          currentRecordModule: null,
          backgroundProcess: false,
          showModal: false
        };
      },
      methods: {
        init() {
          // Placeholder for your module loading logic
          this.moduleLoaded = true;
          this.currentRecordModule = {}; // Set your module object here
        },
        reloadPage() {
          location.reload(true);
        },
        showAlert() {
          this.showModal = true;
          // Additional logic for showing alert
        },
        handleShowBackgroundProcessAlert(event) {
          if (event.target.id === 'showBackgroundProcessAlert') {
            this.showAlert();
          }
        },
        handleOk() {
          this.showModal = false;
        }
      },
      mounted() {
        console.log('App mounted');
        this.init();
        document.addEventListener('click', this.handleShowBackgroundProcessAlert);
      }
    }).mount('#app');
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Moved the Ant Design Vue script to the head section: This ensures that the Ant Design Vue components are loaded before the Vue app is initialized.

Comment: I think there is an issue with there cdn because I have just seen another warning in console saying it is not identifying the ant design components. I have edited the post with that warning

Comment: @IshaqKamran It seems that the Ant Design Vue components are not being exposed as expected when using the CDN. Unfortunately, this is a known issue with some versions of Ant Design Vue when used via CDN, especially with Vue 3.

So better to use Vue2 or change Ant version

Comment: Unfortunately, Ant Design Vue's compatibility with Vue 3 when used via CDN is not as straightforward due to the way components are registered and exported in the ES module format.